# Assign $varText to each $var (optimize if/elseif code)

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, optimization

I have variable `$var`, which can be `"text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"`. I want to assign different `$varWord` for each of `$var`. This code will work for that, but it's very huge, how can I optimize it (making it to have less if/elseif)?

```
<?php
if ($var == "text1") {
    $varWord = "word1";
} elseif ($var == "text2") {
    $varWord = "word2";
} elseif ($var == "text3") {
    $varWord = "word3";
} elseif ($var == "text4") {
    $varWord = "word4";
}
?>
```

Comment: Switch case ? not sure about php though

Comment: Not sure about PHP either, but you could probably use some sort of dictionary mapping `textX` to `wordX`.

Comment: `$words = array('text1' => 'word1', ..); $varWord = $words[$var];`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to deceze . This is final working code:

```
$var = 'text1'; 
$words = array('text1' => 'word1', 'text2' => 'word2', 'text3' => 'word3', 'text4' => 'word4'); 
$varWord = $words[$var];
echo $varWord;
```